# Logical or of strings behaves differently in groovy vs jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-job-dsl

I noticed that in groovy, an expression like `null || 'world'` evaluates to true:

```
$ groovy -v
Groovy Version: 2.4.7 JVM: 1.8.0_60 Vendor: Oracle Corporation OS: Linux
$ cat hello.groovy
print "hello " + (null || "world")
$ groovy hello.groovy
hello true
```

But while experimenting with jenkins pipelines, I stumbled on `null || 'world'` evaluating to `'world'`. e.g. with a pipeline like this:

```
pipeline {
    agent { label 'test' }
    stages {
        stage('Run script') {
            steps {
                print "hello " + (null || "world")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I get output like this:

```
 Running in Durability level: MAX_SURVIVABILITY
 [Pipeline] Start of Pipeline
 [Pipeline] node
 Running on mynode in /path/to/ws
 [Pipeline] {
 [Pipeline] stage
 [Pipeline] { (Run script)
 [Pipeline] echo
 hello world
 [Pipeline] }
 [Pipeline] // stage
 [Pipeline] }
 [Pipeline] // node
 [Pipeline] End of Pipeline
 Finished: SUCCESS
```

In general I'm not super familiar with either groovy or jenkins pipelines, so I just wonder what explains this difference? The latter behavior is the one I prefer -- is it safe to use and rely on?

Comment: There is something different about the Groovy in JP that someone probably could explain really well. Also, the Groovy string `print` method is different than the JP `print` step method. What is clear is that in the former the expression `(null || "world")` is evaluated first, and therefore cast to a boolean. In the latter, the expression `"hello " + ` is evaluated first, and therefore cast to a string. The reason for this is beyond me.

Comment: Some further playing around in jenkins shows that `"" || "world"` is `"world"`, but `"hello" || "world"` is `true`